# Freeing returned variable in C

Tags: c, return, malloc

Say I have the following setup:

```
struct matrix
{
    int row, col;
};

struct matrix* createMatrix(int row, int col)
{
    struct matrix* t_matrix;
    t_matrix = (struct matrix*) malloc(sizeof(struct matrix));
    t_matrix->row = row;
    t_matrix->col = col;

    return t_matrix;
}
```

and then I want to have a function that temporarily returns a struct matrix*, but does not change the original matrix (very important):

```
struct matrix* transpose(struct matrix* mat)
{
    return createMatrix(mat->col, mat->row);
}
```

How do I now free this transposed matrix, but still use its value temporarily?

EDIT: removed unnecessary parameter of createMatrix

SOLVED: As some suggested, I ended up making a pointer to all my matrices and freeing them upon ending the program.

Comment: Note that you `createMatrix()` doesn't take a `struct matrix*`

Comment: Do you see any problem using `free` on the returned value of `transpose`?

Comment: My actual createMatrix function is different than this, so I got a little confused :P I fixed it though.

Comment: @RSahu Where would I do that? I can't free it after it returns, and if I call transpose(matrix) and then I try free(transpose(matrix)) it'll free a different matrix.

Comment: Why it will free different matrix? It'll free same memory...

Comment: @Learner every time I call transpose, it makes a new struct matrix*. So if I call transpose, then free(tranpose), then it'll free a new matrix that is created and the first tranpose in still in use.

Comment: Do something like this `struct matrix* transposeCreated = transpose(mat)` and than call `free( transposeCreated)` whenever you want to free it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you tell in the documentation of the function that it returns a new object matrix (ie, it doesn't change any matrix passed as an argument) and that it is the responsability of the calling code to free it when it's no longer in use.

Another possibility would be to store somewhere the list of these newly created matrix and dispose or reuse them when by some criteria, you know that they are no longer in use; for example by using a flag, a time stamp, etc.

Comment: My question is, how could I free the matrix? I can't call free(tranpose(matrix)) because that'll free a new matrix that is created, so then I'll have two transpose matrices, one will be freed, and then I'll also have the original matrix.

Comment: You need to store the value of each matrix (or more exactly, its address)  in its own pointer or use some sort of collection object to store them.

Answer (score 0):

The key point to remember is there needs to be a `free` for every `malloc`. Here's some example code that illustrates how you could use the functions.

```
// Create a matrix
struct matrix* m1 = createMatrix(10, 15);

// Create a transpose of the matrix.
struct matrix* mt1 = transpose(m1)

// Create another transpose of the matrix.
struct matrix* mt2 = transpose(m1)

// Free the second transposed matrix
free(mt2);

// Free the first transposed matrix
free(mt1);

// Free the original matrix
free(m1);
```